# How to disable queued click events during DOM update?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an "upload" button whose function uses `fetch()` to parse a user-selected CSV file and computes for 1000 - 2000 ms to generate a series of d3 charts. My users have reported that bugs occur if they click any other buttons during this time. So I tried disabling buttons using any/all of the normal suggested methods:

```
$("#my-button").off("click");
$("#my-button").prop("disabled", true);
$("#my-button").css("pointer-events", "none");
```

All of them work if they're left as-is. But when I add lines of code to turn the click back on at the end upload function execution, things go wrong.

What I see from debugging is the following chronology of `"log messages"` and `<user actions>`:

```
0000ms: <user clicks upload button>
0001ms: "buttons disabled!"
0500ms: <user clicks any button>
1000ms: "buttons enabled!"
2000ms: "button clicked!"
```

In other words, the user clicks while the upload function is running and buttons are disabled so no click event is apparently happening from my code. But as soon as my upload function finishes and turns back on the buttons, the user's previous click event suddenly triggers as if it was waiting in a queue.

The only way I've found to handle this situation is to add a `$(document).ready(<enable buttons>)` call at the end of my upload function. This is OK, but not ideal. I want to make sure that click event isn't triggered *at all* during the upload function.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: So are you disabling these buttons by actually disabling them or by using the `jQuery.off()` method? Also, can we see this code?

Comment: Browser does not queue a click so we would need to see what the code is actually doing.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi: Can you explain what "actually disabling" the buttons means? I've seen a bunch of different methods but no canonical way. So far I'm using ` $(":button").css("pointer-events", "none")`.

Comment: @epascarello: I don't know, but it sounds like the clicks themselves aren't queued but the onclick functions they call are. Those triggered onclick functions appear to wait to execute until after the async function completes and the DOM redraws.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Kaiido has a good demonstration of the problem. However, the solutions of offloading to a Worker, hiding the canvas updates offscreen, or reducing reflows were not appropriate to my use case.

My use case involves a complex calculation that is expected to take time to complete and redraw the DOM (users aren't worried about Interaction to Next Paint metrics). Therefore I really do need to disable UI entirely (and prevent queuing).

Here's my solution:

```
function handleEvent(event) {

  var selectedFile = document.getElementById("csvfile").files[0];
  var file = window.URL.createObjectURL(selectedFile);

  $(":button").css("pointer-events", "none"); // disable buttons

  fetch(file)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(async response => {

      // ...heavy data transformation and plotting goes here
    
      // enable ui AFTER dom redraws WITHIN async
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $(":button").css("pointer-events", "auto"); // enable buttons
      })
  
    })
}
```

Explanation:

1. The user clicks a button and triggers `handleEvent` (synchronous)
2. All button pointer events are disabled.
3. Data is fetched and transformed (asynchronous)

If I naively enable pointer events again here in the synchronous part of the code, then it fails to achieve my goal. This is because the synchronous code continues running without waiting for the asynchronous code (so the buttons disable for a few milliseconds and then enable again, meanwhile the asynchronous code continues running in the background).

Additionally, if I naively enable pointer events again at the end of my asynchronous code, then it also fails to achieve my goal. This is because once the DOM manipulations complete and the buttons are enabled, the page must still reflow/layout the new DOM, which in my case takes a significant amount of time. During this time the buttons will be enabled and will queue any UI input, which will immediately trigger as soon as the DOM redraws.

So I combine two different approaches into one:

4. A function to enable all button pointer events is set to trigger only after the DOM redraws (with `$(document).ready()`).

This is done at the end of the asynchronous function, therefore all async DOM modifications are complete and only the DOM reflow is left (and I avoid accidentally triggering a DOM reflow earlier in the code, which would prematurely trigger the buttons to enable).

This means that the synchronous UI code continues to run and receive button click events while the DOM manipulations are being calculated and while the DOM is being redrawn, but the buttons are disabled so these pointer events are handled (ie they don't queue) and do nothing. Only when the DOM is fully redrawn does it allow the buttons to work again.

Comment: This is actually the solution labelled "the worst solution" at the bottom of my answer. Except that you're relying on the fact that `$.ready()` is implicitly wrapped in a `setTimeout(fn, 0)` when called after the page already did load. However you don't know how many times the user will have clicked, nor how long it will take the browser to process all these events (because even if your code doesn't handle it, the browser still will fire it and some other part of your page might execute some processing based on that).

Comment: And then you're relying on the task prioritization system of the browser to handle your implicit timeout after **all** the click events. This isn't a given, for instance [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sq2jkgyc/) does fail in Firefox and Safari, and it could also fail in Chrome under some complex circumstances. That's why I did set a 10ms delay in my answer. That may not cover all the cases but at least the most common ones.

Comment: Thank you for adding that explanation. So is this `setTimeout()` method the only option available for my use case? I think the issue here is that both the DOM manipulation and layout steps take so long to process, but the layout/reflow step has so far been out of my control. Is there a way to force the reflow to occur so that I guarantee it happens within my enable/disable code?

Comment: Yes you can force a reflow (e.g. `document.body offsetWidth` will do that), but I doubt this is your issue.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use a boolean flag to keep track of whether or not the upload function is currently running. When the flag is set to true, you can disable all buttons except for the upload button. When the flag is set to false, you can enable all buttons again.

Here's an example implementation:

```
let uploadRunning = false;

function handleUploadClick() {
  if (uploadRunning) {
    return;
  }

  disableButtons();

  // Set uploadRunning to true before starting long-running operation
  uploadRunning = true;

  // Perform long-running operation
  doSomeWork().then(() => {
    // Set uploadRunning to false when operation completes
    uploadRunning = false;

    // Enable buttons when operation completes
    enableButtons();
  });
}

function disableButtons() {
  $("button").prop("disabled", true);
  $("#upload-button").prop("disabled", false);
}

function enableButtons() {
  $("button").prop("disabled", false);
}

function doSomeWork() {
  // Perform long-running operation here
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
}
```

In this implementation, the uploadRunning flag is used to prevent any buttons from being clickable while the upload function is running, except for the upload button itself. When uploadRunning is set to false again, all buttons are re-enabled.

This should prevent the issue of queued up click events triggering after the upload function finishes.

Comment: This won't work. Here you'll lower the flag before the events actually fired, and thus for the events, it's like it was never raised.

Answer (score 1):

The thing that must be happening here is that your code blocks the event loop during this whole time.
Browsers do use multiple processes, and while the rendering one will wait for the event-loop to be free, the one responsible for queuing the UI events won't. So after the event-loop is freed, all the events queued by the UI process will be fired one after the other in a small burst. This can be demonstrated quite easily:

```js
let i = 0;
let blocked = false;
document.querySelector("button").onclick = (evt) => {
  if (blocked) {
    return; // will not work 
  }
  blocked = true; // useless
  i = 0; // reset the counter
  console.log("blocking the event loop for 5s.");
  console.log("click anywhere during this period");
  // let the console message print
  requestAnimationFrame(() => setTimeout(() => {
    // block the event-loop for 5s
    const t1 = performance.now();
    while(performance.now() - t1 < 5000) {}
    console.log("releasing the event loop.");
    blocked = false;
  }));
};
onclick = (evt) => {
  if (blocked) {
    return; // will not work 
  }
  console.log("clicked %s times", ++i);
};
```

```html
<button>click here</button>
```

As you can see, the synchronous log "releasing the event loop." appears before the next "clicked 1 times". This is because while the UI process kept working and queued the events, the main process, also responsible for the JS execution was blocked and resumed where it was. So all your attempts to prevent the click from happening were moot because the event callbacks would only be executed **after** you unlocked the button. For these, it's as if the button was never blocked.

---

To avoid that, **the best is to not block the event-loop**. You don't really show what you are doing, so it's hard to tell what you should do exactly, but some common strategies involve:

- Purely arithmetic computation / data transformation (heavy ones), should be moved to a second thread, using a [web worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker). This allows to keep your main thread and its rendering process working seamlessly. This way you can await nicely that the asynchronous job is done before unlocking your buttons.
- If your visualizations are done on a `<canvas>`and that the drawing is the culprit, try to improve it, and you can consider using an [`OffscreenCanvas`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvas) that you'd also transfer to a web worker.
- If the culprit is due to DOM manipulations, you won't be able to transfer that to a worker, they don't have access to the DOM. So instead, make sure that your code doesn't [trigger unnecessary "reflows"](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a). This operation forces the CSSOM to recalculate all of the elements' boxes. Misused it can become a perf' killer. If you must get computed styles during your DOM manipulations, be sure to batch them all in the same place and to do the changes that would dirty the layout after you've had all the getters.
- If you have several visualizations being rendered at the same time, try to render only the ones that would be visible in the screen first, and then wait that a first batch is done before continuing with the other ones. Space each of these in `setTimeout()` calls, this will give the browser time to render what it has to render, and to process the UI events. Tasks coming from the [UI task source](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#user-interaction-task-source) usually have the highest priority in the event-loop.
- If you've got only one visualization that still takes more than a few hundred ms, you can try to split it's rendering algorithm and space it in `setTimeout()` calls.

---

If none of these solution is applicable to you, the worst solution possible would be to wrap the code that does reenable the button in a `setTimeout()` callback. To be safe you may pass something like `10`ms as the second argument. But really, this is the worst solution.

```js
let i = 0;
let blocked = false;
document.querySelector("button").onclick = (evt) => {
  if (blocked) {
    return; // will now work 
  }
  blocked = true;
  i = 0; // reset the counter
  console.log("blocking the event loop for 5s.");
  console.log("click anywhere during this period");
  // let the console message print
  requestAnimationFrame(() => setTimeout(() => {
    // block the event-loop for 5s
    const t1 = performance.now();
    while(performance.now() - t1 < 5000) {}
    console.log("releasing the event loop.");
    setTimeout(() => blocked = false, 10);
  }));
};
onclick = (evt) => {
  if (blocked) {
    return; // will now work 
  }
  console.log("clicked %s times", ++i);
};
```

```html
<button>click here</button>
```